# Button Click doesn't work to make a H1 visible (asp.net)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm new at ASP.NET and web programming in general, here's my issue.

I have this DIV in my .aspx:

```
<div class="login">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Usuário" name="usuario" id="usuario" runat="server"><br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" name="senha" id="senha" runat="server"><br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn-sucess" id="btn" runat="server" onserverclick="btn_Click" onclick="btn_Click">Login</button>
            <h1 id="lbl1" runat="server" visible="false">Sucess</h1>
    </div>
```

If the user clicks on the submit button it should be visible as it's written here in my aspx.cs

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl1.Visible = true;
}
```

Nothing happens. Why it doesn't work?

Comment: why is this here - onclick="btn_Click"...is there a javascript function of the same name...you should only need the onserverclick attribute in my opinion

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `lbl1.Visible = true;` and run the code, does the breakpoint get hit? What happens after the submit button is clicked (do they stay on the same page? go to a different page?)?

Comment: After the submit button is clicked it will stay on the same page because I'm still testing the login page, but the button isn't working, for testing purposes I inserted this H1 as example to see if the button is working, so if it's working it should be visible, if it's not it should stay hidden.

Comment: @Ctznkane525 I was testing onclick and onserverclick, if it changes anything. I removed onclick and nothing changed.

Comment: @mjwills The breakpoint doesn't get hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting it to `Visible` false when rendering the control. Remove the `visible` property from aspx code and handle it in `Page_Load` event. All controls need to be inside `form`.

**aspx**

```
<form runat="server">
<div class="login">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Usuário" name="usuario" id="usuario" runat="server"><br>
   <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" name="senha" id="senha" runat="server"><br>
   <button type="submit" class="btn-sucess" id="btn" runat="server" onserverclick="btn_Click" onclick="btn_Click">Login</button>
   <h1 id="lbl1" runat="server">Sucess</h1>
</div>
</form>
```

**Code-Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  lbl1.Visible = false;
}
```

With button click

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl1.Visible = true;
}
```

Also, if you want to handle anything at a client side, then alone use a javascript function `btn_Click`. But make sure that returns true and so the form will be submitted to the server.

Something like this,

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function btn_Click()
    {
       return true;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Def a combination of the unnecessary onclick, and the hard coded visible="false". I would assume that the onclick was put there to try to get the server side method to run, but in fact broke the post back.

Comment: I tried testing and you need to remove the onclick entirely. The rendered page *with* the onclick looks like this <button onclick="btn_Click __doPostBack('btn','')" ... which doesn't hit the function at all.

Comment: Yes, `.NET` will map the events like this `__doPostBack` which is correct

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm very new at web programming, I didn't know that I had to use Javascript to work. The function btn_click is on the .cs file

Comment: @Pvxtotal, check my edited answer, it is not needed that you've to use Javascript to make it work.

Comment: @Pvxtotal, Use javascript for any cases like client validation and some scenarios which needs to be handled in the browser side.